# How to use GROUPBY function in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I tried using group by DAX function in PowerBI as Measure, New Column, New Table but I get an error in validating the function,

```
New Table = GROUPBY(
            'tab1',
            'tab1'[color],
            "Group By color",
            sum('tab1'[count_lables])
          )

Error : Function 'GROUPBY' scalar expressions have to be Aggregation functions over CurrentGroup(). The expression of each Aggregation has to be either a constant or directly reference the columns in CurrentGroup().
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error says you need to use an aggregation function over a group, you are using `SUM` function which doesn't sum values over any group. In your case you need to use `SUMX` aggregation function with `CURRENTGROUP()` option. The `CURRENTGROUP` determines the groups that must be added based on the current row.

Try using the below expression instead.

```
New Table = GROUPBY (
        tab1,
        tab1[color],
        "Group by color", SUMX ( CURRENTGROUP (), tab1[count lables] )
    )
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks @alejandro zuleta it works for me now, do you know material that can be referred for usage of GROUPBY AND SUMMERIZE  in Power BI?

Comment: @DaveD., you are welcome. Sure, check [this great](http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/nested-grouping-using-groupby-vs-summarize/) article by Marco Russo.